# Как в готовом коде менять смещение переменных не меняя самого кода?

Tags: ассемблер, переменные

Есть процедура, с написанным кодом и в ней есть переменные (я сделал на переменных, а не стеке передачу параметров процедуре так как я ещё не дорос до проф уровня).
Мне надо не меняя кода самой процедуры сделать смещение переменных на нужное значение (понятно дело что указатель). Это значение будет меняться.

Comment: Приведите хоть какой-то код, без кода не очень понятно.

Comment: Параметры процедурам можно передавать или через регистры, или через стек. Причём здесь переменные? Если со-стеком не знаком, то вызывай процедуру с уже подготовленными в регистрах значениями, а внутри процедуры работай с регистрами.

Comment: Я понимаю что такое стек, просто под стек все процедуры надо переделывать.

Comment: Я использую фасм, так что переменные имеют место быть

Comment: Если ты пишешь на Асм то передача параметров через стек это плохой способ, параметры нужно передавать через регистры.

Comment: @ИльяК "всегда" через стек передавали параметры в процедуры, а тут вдруг это стало плохим способом?

Comment: @insolor уже очень давно, прямо сразу как придумали vectorcall

Answer (score 0):

Вот варианты передачи аргументов через регистры и через стек (fasm):

```
format   pe gui
include 'win32ax.inc'
;//----------
.data
szMes1   db  'Передача параметров через регистры!',0
szMes2   db  'Передача параметров через стек!',0
buff     db  0
;//----------
.code
start:
       mov     ebx,szMes1    ;// аргумент в регистре EBX
       call    Registers

       push    szMes2        ;// аргумент в стеке
       call    Stacks

       invoke  ExitProcess,0
;//------------
proc   Registers
       invoke  MessageBox,0,ebx,<'Fasm example',0>,0
       ret
endp
proc   Stacks param1
       mov     ebx,[param1]
       invoke  MessageBox,0,ebx,<'Fasm example',0>,0
       ret
endp
.end start
```